# configure apache to use sql server authentication using password and salt

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, security, authentication, web-applications

I got a web application which I want to protect using apache authentication. I found out that it uses sha1+salt to store passwords. Since `auth_mysql_module` is deprecated I try to use `authn_dbd_module`. Currently I'm running debian wheezy.
Here is how the web-app creates password-hashes:

```
<?php sha1($pw.$salt); ?>
```

try with php:

```
sha1('password'.'salt')
c88e9c67041a74e0357befdff93f87dde0904214
```

I can reproduce the hash using mysql:

```
SELECT SHA1(CONCAT(@pw, @salt));
```

try using mysql:

```
mysql> SELECT SHA1(CONCAT('password', 'salt'));
+------------------------------------------+
| SHA1(CONCAT('password', 'salt'))         |
+------------------------------------------+
| c88e9c67041a74e0357befdff93f87dde0904214 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

My `apache site.conf`:

```
    DBDriver mysql
    DBDParams "host=localhost user=<db_user> pass=<db_pass> dbname=<db_name>"

    <Directory /var/www/htdocs/>
       Options -Indexes
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all

       AuthName "Please enter username and password"
       Authtype Basic
       require valid-user

       AuthBasicProvider dbd
       AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT SHA1(CONCAT(password, salt)) AS password FROM users WHERE username = %s"

    </Directory>
```

The `AuthDBDUserPWQuery` line obviously doesn't do the trick because it creates a new hash from (stored hash and salt) and compares it to the entered password. And  Apache-log:

```
[Sat Aug 22 XX:XX:XX 2015] [error] [client 92.X.X.X] user myusername: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch
```

I know it is neither recommended to use sha1 nor short salt to store passwords. But anyhow: is there a way to make the authentication work?